# Using classes instead of global variables

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I have a program to do some operations with an array (wavelet transformations and various other complexities), then compare it to the previous array and its properties, output a graph comparing the two, and finally update the 'previous' array to contain this information.
Basically my program is starting to get a little long and hard to read, but I can't really split it up into functions because all the functions are reading in and changing the same variables. Without defining all these variables as global everytime I want a function to alter them, it's quite hard.

Then I found this online:

> You may have several functions that use the same state variables, either reading or writing them. You are passing a lot of parameters around. You have nested functions that have to forward their parameters to the functions they use. You are tempted to make some module variables to hold the state.
>
> You could make a class instead! All methods of a class have access to all istance data of the class. By storing the shared state in the class, you avoid the need to pass it as parameters to the methods.

So I was wondering how can I adapt my program to be written using classes instead?
I can attach my code if it helps, but it's quite long and I don't want to fill up the forum!

Here is the code:

```
import os, sys, string, math
from optparse import OptionParser
import numpy as np
import pywt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import glob

dir = os.getcwd()
profiles = glob.glob(dir+"/B0740-28/*_edit.FT.ascii")
for x in range(0,len(profiles)):
    profiles[x] = profiles[x][28:]
#produce list of profile file names

mode = 'per'
wavelets = ['db12']
levels = range(3,4)
starts = []
fig = 1
ix = 0 #profile index
changes = np.zeros(len(profiles))
#array to record shape changes

for num_levels in levels:
    for wavelet in wavelets:
        for profile in profiles:

            prof_name = profile.partition('.')[0]
            #remove file extension

            pfile=open(dir+'/B0740-28/'+profile)
            data = []
            for line in pfile:
                data.append(float(line))
            data = np.array(data)
            end = len(data)
            data = np.array(data)/max(data)
            #get pulse profile and normalise
            #ignore first 2 lines

            wav_name = wavelet.partition('.')[0]
            w = pywt.Wavelet(wavelet)
            useful = pywt.dwt_max_level(end,w)
            #find max level of decomposition

            coeffs = pywt.wavedec(data,wavelet,mode,level=num_levels)
            #create wavelet coefficients: cAn, cDn, cD(n-1)... cD1

            lowpass = pywt.upcoef('a',coeffs[0],wavelet,level=num_levels,take=end)
            highpass = np.zeros(end)
            for x in range(1,(num_levels+1)):
                highpass += pywt.upcoef('d',coeffs[len(coeffs)-x],wavelet,\
                                        level=x,take=end)
            #reverse transform by upcoef
            #define highpass and lowpass components

            for n in range(0,len(data)):
                if float(data[n]) > 0.4:
                    value = n
                    starts.append(value)
                    break
            if profile != profiles[0]:
                offset = starts[0]- value
                data = np.roll(data,offset)
                lowpass = np.roll(lowpass,offset)
                highpass = np.roll(highpass,offset)
            #adjust profiles so that they line up
            
            if profile == profiles[0]:
                data_prev = 0
                lowpass_prev = 0
                highpass_prev = 0
                mxm = data.argmax()

            diff_low = lowpass - lowpass_prev
            diff_high = highpass - highpass_prev
            if max(diff_low) >= 0.15 or min(diff_low) <= -0.15:
                changes[ix] = 1
            else: changes[ix] = 0
            #significant change?

            def doPlotting(name,yaxis):
                plt.plot(name)
                plt.xlim([mxm-80,mxm+100])
                plt.ylabel(yaxis)
                plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=4))
            
            figure = plt.figure(fig)
            figure.subplots_adjust(hspace =.5)
            plt.suptitle('Comparison of Consecutive Profiles')
            plt.subplot(411); plt.plot(data_prev); \
                              doPlotting(data,'Data'); plt.ylim(ymax=1.1)
            plt.subplot(412); plt.plot(lowpass_prev); \
                              doPlotting(lowpass,'Lowpass'); plt.ylim(ymax=1.1)
            plt.subplot(413); plt.plot(highpass_prev); doPlotting(highpass,'Highpass')
            plt.subplot(414); doPlotting(diff_low,'Lowpass\nChange')
            plotname = 'differences_'+str(ix+1)+'_'+wav_name+'_'+str(num_levels)
            plt.savefig(dir+'/B0740-28/Plots/'+plotname)
            #creates plots of two most recent profiles + their decomposition 

            fig += 1
            ix += 1
            #clears the figure content
            #increase array index

            data_prev = data
            lowpass_prev = lowpass
            highpass_prev = highpass
            #reassigns 'previous profile' values

figure = plt.figure(fig)
plt.plot(changes)
plt.title('Lowpass Changes')
plt.xlabel('Profile Number')
plt.ylabel('Change > Threshold?')
plt.ylim(-0.25,1.25)
plt.xlim(0,48)
plt.savefig(dir+'/B0740-28/Plots/changes')
#Save lowpass changes plot
```

Comment: You may as well post your code - it'll be put in a scrolling box if it's too long

Comment: I'd start by making functions that take lots of arguments, then work out which bits of code need which variables.

Answer (score 4):

I'll probably get downvoted for this answer, but in the grand scheme of things, in this particular situation, I don't really see the problem with adding some global variables to your package.

Classes are great and useful when you have a bunch of functionality that you want to use in lots of different places, however, what you are describing sounds very specific and unlikely to be reused elsewhere. Creating a one-use class with instance variables isn't really very different to having a bunch of functions in a package with global variables.

Comment: _"operations with an array..., then compare it to the previous array and its properties"_ - sounds like a prime candidate for having two instances of a class here

Comment: Thanks :) so is there some way for me to define certain variables as global, like right from the start of the program, so that they can be seen and edited by all the different functions?

Comment: I think you mean "modules" not packages (which are different things in Python). The former are instances of built-in class `module` with the things defined in them being instance attributes — so doing what you say ***is*** using a class…

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is what you want:

```
class MyDataProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self, data_array):
        self.data_array = data_array

    def processX(self):
        # do stuff with self.data_array

    def processY(self):
        # do stuff with self.data_array

m = MyDataProcessor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
m.processX()

n = MyDataProcessor([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
n.processX()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful! I have a lot more variables than just data_array though, there might be about 10, and I'm looping over 47/48 different cases (reading each array from a file) so I can't really do m =, n= etc. At the moment I'm reading all the arrays in from a file, and then looping over them.

Comment: @HelenJohnson: How many of those variables need to be global? Could some of them be used in only one function? At any rate, you can just add more arguments to the constructor.

Comment: Using classes doesn't really get rid of globals because the instances of them — such as `m` and `n` in your answer which are still a global variables. Using them is still a good practice though, because they can greatly reduce the number of them needed and typically [encapsulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) access to stuff that might otherwise have been individual global variables.